# How to make c# Random Numbers repeat

Tags: c#, random, numbers, repeat

I'm trying to generate random arrays to test my homework assignments.
The Problem is that the numbers generated are always unique , and I need some repeating numbers from time to time.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
static int[] RandomIntArray()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Console.Write("Enter array Length: ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rnd.Next(short.MinValue, short.MaxValue);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the same number repeated? Or You wish to create the same pattern of random numbers?

Comment: random is random, what do you expect? if you want repeating numbers, make the range smaller. if there's thousands of options, you'd have to have thousands generated to expect duplicates.

Comment: Random is random. If you want it to repeat once in a while, have a smaller range, or build in your own logic (like `if (i % 100 == 0) arr[i] = arr[i-1];` or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: they will repeat/have duplicate at some point!

Comment: @Dleh I swear I didn't copy your answer - you were just 4 seconds faster than me :)

Comment: @JoeEnos I know, we're just on the same page ^_^

Comment: It is obvious that he wants repeatable random number sequences. Geez...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can seed a random number generator, so it will always produce the same random sequence:

```
Random rnd = new Random(1/* Any seed value you want in here */);
```

If you want to force some repeating numbers, you could so something like this:

```
static int[] RandomIntArray()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Console.Write("Enter array Length: ");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i > 0 && rnd.Next(10) == 1) // a 1 in 10 chance of a dupe
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i-1]; 
        }
        else
            arr[i] = rnd.Next(short.MinValue, short.MaxValue);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that he meant that he wants to have sequences of repeating numbers every once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

If you want numbers to repeat once in a while, make the range smaller. They'll be more likely to result in duplicates.

```
    arr[i] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

How often you want repeated numbers will dictate what approach you use.  You could always round the random numbers you get to the nearest 10, 100, whatever until the "bins" are big enough that the "bins" show up as often as you want.  This is similar to making the range smaller as suggested by @DLeh, but it allows you to spread the generated numbers over a larger range.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialized random with same seed, you will get same sequence of numbers all the time

```
Random rnd1 = new Random(5);
Random rnd2 = new Random(5);

for(var i=0;i<10; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(rnd1.Next() + ", " + rnd2.Next());
}
```